# How to calculate enthalpy by using mutate for each column in R?

Tags: r, function, dplyr, tibble

I would like to calculate enthalpy by using [steam table function](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/IAPWS95/index.html) .
I want to adapt the function to a Tibble table which include temp and pressure, but failed.
For example, I want to add the enthalpy row.

```
sample_table    

temp pressure
800  16
900  17
1000 18

sample_table_add_enthalpy <- sample_table %>%
  mutate(enthalpy = hTp(temp, pressure))
```

The result is

```
temp pressure enthalpy
800  16     3375.08509
900  17     3375.08509
1000 18     3375.08509
```

In this case, the calculation is only adapted to the first column.
How should I do to calculate for all column by using mutate?

Comment: It appears to me (though I am not *certain*) that `hTp` is expecting singles, not vectors, for its arguments. Does `mutate(enthalpy = mapply(hTp, temp, pressure))` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thinking more about your question, now I understand that you were not talking about multiple columns. Instead, it seems like you would like to have a function that can process data for multiple rows.

Here I provided two solutions. The first one is to use `Vectorize` function to covert your function to a version that can generate vectorized output.

```
library(IAPWS95)
library(tidyverse)

hTp_vectorize <- Vectorize(hTp)

sample_table_add_enthalpy <- sample_table %>%
  mutate(enthalpy = hTp_vectorize(temp, pressure))

sample_table_add_enthalpy
#   temp pressure   enthalpy
# 1  800       16 3375.08509
# 2  900       17 3636.88144
# 3 1000       18 3889.57761
```

The second one is to use `map2` from the `purrr` package to vectorized the operations.

```
sample_table_add_enthalpy <- sample_table %>%
  mutate(enthalpy = map2(temp, pressure, hTp))

sample_table_add_enthalpy
#   temp pressure   enthalpy
# 1  800       16 3375.08509
# 2  900       17 3636.88144
# 3 1000       18 3889.57761
```